# avoiding "content" line in table of contents for amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using document class amsbook.

I create the table of contents via:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
Blah blah
\SkipTocEntry\chapter*{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

The `\SkipTocEntry` command causes the following chapter heading to be omitted from the table of contents.

The table of contents is printed but it is followed by a line:

```
Contents
```

I have a similar problem with the list of figures.

How do I get rid of the "Contents" line in the table of contents"

Here's what I've tried, this time showing the preceeding chapter, which is the abstract

Try #1:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
Blah blah
\tableofcontents
```

On try #1, I don't get a header for the table of contents and a line with "Contents" still appears after the table of contents.

Try #2:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

I still get a line with "Contents" after the table of contents.

In both try #1 and try #2, the chapter heading "Abstract" appears at the top of the page.

Any ideas? I want a chapter heading "Table of Contents" and I want to git rid of the "Contents" line after the table of contents. My code is the original code block at the top of this post.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` already makes a chapter head so you are making two chapters, Just remove `\chapter*(Table of Contents}`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. See the revised question for what happened.

Comment: Don't post fragments post documents that demonstrate the problem, but you should not have `\chaper*` before the `\tableofcontents` As I said in the first comment simply remove that command.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a custom chapter name for Table of Contents. So in addition to omitting

```
\chapter*{Table of Contents}
```

add this:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
```